# Peak to peak amplitude of sum of sinusoidals (harmonic frequencies)

Tags: frequency-spectrum, amplitude

I would like to estimate the peak-to-peak amplitude of a periodic signal whose frequency components are known. This is, I have the frequency spectrum (a peak in the fundamental frequency and other peaks in its harmonics) and I would like to compute the peak-to-peak amplitude. Is that possible without reconstructing the signal in the time domain and then detecting peaks?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose that we have a continuous-time periodic signal
$\displaystyle s(t) = a_0 + \sum_{n=1}^N a_n \cos(n\omega_0 t + \theta_n)$.

What does this mean? Do we have a  trace of $s(t)$ on some recorder chart
and the trace looks periodic?  If we did, the question to be solved would be
trivial since we could simply *measure* the maximum and minimum values of $s(t)$ on
the chart.  So the problem of interest is:

> Given the values of 
>   $\omega_0, a_0, a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_N, \theta_1, \theta_2, \cdots, \theta_N$,
>   find the values of 
>   $$M_\max = \max s(t)\quad \operatorname{and} \quad M_\min =  \min s(t).$$

The OP wants to find the *peak-to-peak amplitude* of $s(t)$ and this is, of
course, just $M_\max-M_\min$.  It is worth noting that since $s(t)$ is periodic
with period $T = \frac{2\pi}{\omega_0}$, the maximum value and minimum value
occur (at least once) in each interval of length $T$ on the time axis.  The key
issue here is since we know the $a_i$ and the $\theta_i$ etc., we can write
down the *formula*
$$s(t) = a_0 + \sum_{n=1}^N a_n \cos(n\omega_0 t + \theta_n)\tag{1}$$
(whether this constitutes "reconstruction" of the time-domain signal
is a question that I will leave to others to answer) but the
standard method for finding the maxima and minima of $s(t)$
requires us to find solutions to the *nonlinear* equation $(2)$ below
(that is, values of $t$ for which $(2)$ holds):
$$\frac{ds(t)}{dt} = -\sum_{n=1}^N a_n\cdot n\omega_0 \sin(n\omega_0 t + \theta_n) = 0.
\tag{2}$$
Once we have *found* the values $t_1, t_2, \ldots, t_k, \ldots$ for which
$\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^N a_n\cdot n\omega_0 \sin(n\omega_0 t_k + \theta_n) = 0$,
we can simply calculate $s(t_1), s(t_2), \ldots, s(t_k), \ldots$ and *search
through this list of numbers* (it is *not* necessary to *sort* the list
as recommended in hotpaw2's answer) to find $M_\max$ and $M_\min$.  But,
ignoring the difficulty of finding the $t_k$'s makes hotpaw's answer not
particularly useful in solving the OP's problem.  The answer by ethereal
is even worse in this regard since all it boils down to is the assertion
that (for $\alpha > 0$)
the maximum and minimum values of $\alpha\cdot s(t)$ are $\alpha\cdot M_\max$ 
and $\alpha\cdot M_\min$ respectively. Finding the maximum and minimum
of $s(t)$ from knowledge of its Fourier series is a nontrivial task, not at
all as easy as it is made out to be by ethereal or by hotpaw2.

---

A related problem has received a lot of research attention in the past
thirty years or so.  For a periodic signal such as $s(t)$, the *average* power
in the signal is readily computed as 
$$\bar{P} = \frac{1}{T}\int_0^T |s(t)|^2\,\mathrm dt = a_0^2 + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^N |a_i|^2.$$
On the other hand, the *peak* power is $P_\max = \max\{M_\max^2, M_\min^2\}$,
and is also of interest, especially to system and power amplifier designers,
and the ratio $\frac{P_\max}{\bar{P}}$, aptly named the _peak-to-average-power 
ratio (PAPR) has received much attention. It *can* be calculated exactly for
a given $s(t)$ but only with great computational effort, and so a lot of effort
has gone into finding bounds on the PAPR.  Some of these could help in getting
bounds for the OP's problem.
only with a great deal of effort.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer. I'm going to search bibliography about PAPR, although it seems that maybe reconstructing the signal in the time domain will be an easier solution after all :S

Comment: Hi, can you take a look at this question, please?
https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/70787/multiple-peaks-in-a-same-signal

Answer (score 1):

For periodic signals, the maximum peak-to-peak amplitude is dependent in the relative phase of each harmonic, as well as their magnitudes.  Do you have that information?  If so, you can numerically evaluate all the local maxima and minima and sort.

Comment: But that requires reconstructing the signal, which the OP doesn't want to do.

Comment: Only the local extrema, which does not require reconstructing the entire signal.

Comment: The calculation of the locations of the maxima and minima of the functions is a nontrivial task, and that is precisely the point that you fail to discuss.

Comment: The question does not specify that a trivial solution is required.  Only non-reconstruction.

Comment: @hotpaw2 A flippant response intended to obscure the truly unhelpful nature of your answer? You dismiss the hard part of the problem -- the difficulty of _finding_ the locations of the maxima and minima -- as not worthy of discussion and give an unnecessarily complicated solution to the easy part. It is **not** necessary to **sort** (an $O(n \log n)$ process) through the values of the local maxima and minima to find the global maximum and minimum: a simple linear search (an $O(n)$ process) suffices.

Comment: Hi, can you take a look at this question, please?
https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/70787/multiple-peaks-in-a-same-signal

Answer (score -2):

Consider the linearity property of the DFT: [image: linearity]

This indicates that the DFT amplitude scales directly with the time domain amplitude of your signal.  Therefore, you should be able to deduce the time domain amplitude directly from the frequency domain amplitude empirically; find the DFT amplitude of a baseline or unity TD signal, and from that you can easily compute a scaling factor that can be applied to your spectral peaks to derive the TD amplitude.

Comment: Of course the DFT amplitude scales with the signal amplitude. But the maximum amplitude of the time-domain signal depends on how the different harmonics add up. So the phase as well as the magnitude are important, and so given the (complex) coefficients it is not so straightforward to determine the time-domain amplitude. So what "baseline or unity TD signal" would you use?

Comment: This answer has mostly incorrect conclusions. The problem of finding the peak amplitude of a sum of sinusoids is an area of active research, and _peak to average power ratio_ is what one should be asking about on search engines.

Comment: @MattL., the OP indicated a well known sum of sinusoids.  Creation of the baseline signal is left to the reader.

Comment: @DilipSarwate if the OP is indeed looking for papr, then you are correct, he would be best served reading about the numerous existing implementations!

Comment: @ethereal: what do you mean by "a well known sum of sinusoids"? In the question only a spectrum of harmonics is mentioned, just as is the case for any periodic signal. And "left to the reader" is a funny way of saying that either you are not able or willing to help. Your answer is misleading and not to the point.

Comment: @MattL. I took "frequency components are known" to indicate a well known sum of sinusoids.  I did not specify the baseline metric calculation because I considered it trivial enough to exclude.