# Multiple peaks in a same signal?

Tags: filters, signal-analysis, wavelet, sound, peak-detection

I am working on peak detection in different signals, the signal plot looks like this:

[image]

After applying peak detection algorithm and tuning it for each signal, final output looks like this:

[image]

As you can see in figure 3 and figure 4, there are more than 2 peaks in a single point, for example in figure 3 there are two peaks from time 0.4 to 0.5 and 0.3 to 0.35 also two peaks. I am quite new in DSP, I wanted to confirm, is it ok to showcase this diagram, the algorithm is detecting the peaks correctly or should I show only one peak in figure 3 from 0.3 to 0.35 and 0.4 to 0.5 like below diagram?

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Somehow I find it strange that in the 2nd picture, fig. 3, the peaks #3 and #4 from the left are marked, but in fig. 4 and fig. 5 there are similar peaks that are not marked. So, I don't know how you calculated those peaks, but it sounds like you need to define some sort of an additional window of detection, even if in the last picture, fig. 3 and fig. 4 show the second peak of each as being quite buried between two adjacent, larger peaks.

Answer (score 3):

> is it ok to showcase this diagram ?

Sorry, we can't tell you this. This is really a function of your specific application, the physics behind your signal, and how you exactly define "peak".

DSP can offer you methods to suppress "near by" peaks or to de-noise multiple peaks but whether that's the right thing to do or not depends largely on what do want to do with the results and what else you already know about the signal.

Comment: I've added a new diagram, Which one would you suggest to go for when the use case is showing the difference between four audio signals?

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment due to low rep but I'm adding to Hilmar's answer and your comment on their answer. Quoting: "Which one would you suggest to go for when the use case is showing the difference between four audio signals?"

This really depends on what information you're trying to convey to whoever you're presenting to. You said these are audio signals and you want to show the difference between them. Are these peaks related to some sort of event? Maybe you could convert the signals from time domain to frequency domain and see if the 4 signals have different frequency characteristics and possibly highlight how they differ there.